# Finding RSS Feeds and displaying RSS Feeds on website using asp.net, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

I have seen many of website are displaying RSS Feeds on their website.

Example:

1) compgroups.net

2) velocityreviews.com

3) bytes.com

4) eggheadcafe.com
And many other websites.

What i observe is Google is even giving them good rank despite of duplicate content.

What i want to know is...

How can I find RSS Feeds?  Also where can i found RSS Feeds for Yahoogroups?

Comment: By `finding RSS feeds`, do you mean you want to find them programatically? Or just find them on internet?

Comment: 1) I want to know, what is source of RSS, which they are displaying on their website.
2) I want to know how to show RSS of Yahoogroup threads.  Yahoogroup is not exposing whole thread, how can i get whole thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read here: http://help.yahoo.com/l/ca/yahoo/groups/rss/rss-03.html

The source of an RSS feed is XML. You can request a feed from c# using the HttpRequest, providing the url of the feed.
You read in the XML, process it and show its contents in your webpage.